# Why R doesn't show digit after decimal point in numeric data type?

Tags: r, dataframe, types, numeric

I have a data frame read from a file into R. Data contains some numeric columns some with digit after decimal point and some column do not have. The columns without values with digit after decimal points have an issue as the following:
If I do some manipulation into that column which result in values with some digit after decimal point. However, the final data has some numbers such as 22.5, R does not show the value in this format, it only shows 22. But if I check it in If condition it confirm the value is actually 22.5. This does not happen when the original data contains some decimal points.

Could anyone let me know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is a FAQ.  *Presentation* may be different from content as it is generally optimised for meaningful output.  Really simple example follows:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=c(10000.12, 10000.13), b=c(42L, 43L))
> df
        a  b
1 10000.1 42
2 10000.1 43
> all.equal(df[1,"a"], 10000.12)
[1] TRUE
>
```

So the last digit did not "disappear" as the test confirms---it is simply beyond the (six in the default) digits displayed.

Similarly, you can always *explicitly* display with more decimals than the (compact, default) displays do:

```
> cat(sprintf("%14.8f", df[1,"a"]), "\n")
10000.12000000 
>
```

*Edit* You can also increate the default display size by one or more:
`options(digits=7)` is the minimal change but not *all* columns use seven digits:

```
> options(digits=7)
> df
         a  b
1 10000.12 42
2 10000.13 43
>
```

Needless to say, if you had digits `.123` only the first two would be shown etc.

Comment: Is there any way to make R to treat this column as other numeric columns? this is very misleading If view() function just shows the digit before decimal point.

Comment: See my edit right now: you can increase the default display size (at the cost of it taking more room).